# Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication Code Verification : The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two pages. One page is to enter the phone number and then the second screen is to enter the verification code sent to the phone number, so that I can verify that .

Although I am sending the correct verification code I am getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.

This is the page to enter the phone number :

```
class PhoneNumberEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhoneNumberEntry({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PhoneNumberEntry> createState() => _PhoneNumberEntryState();
}

class _PhoneNumberEntryState extends State<PhoneNumberEntry> {
  TextEditingController _phonenumber = TextEditingController();

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String verificationID = "";

  void loginWithPhone() async {
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: _phonenumber.text,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
          print("You are logged in successfully");
        });
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        setState(() {
          verificationID = verificationId;
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PhoneNumberVerification(
                        phonenumber: _phonenumber.text,
                        auth: auth,
                        verificationId: verificationID,
                      )));
        });
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0XFF0B1630),
                    Color(0XFF2C496A),
                  ]),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("asset/images/SpirationDark.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Let us',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                        color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Know Your',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                      fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Mobile Number',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                        color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 6.0, 8.0, 0),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: const Text(
                    'To track your expenses and to use other features we need to use your mobile number.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                        color: Colors.grey),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 10),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _phonenumber,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter your Phone Number",
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'SfProDisplay',
                      ),
                      fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
                      filled: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontFamily: 'SfProDisplay',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.grey,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  loginWithPhone();
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Continue',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'SfProRounded',
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: primarycolor,
    );
  }
}
```

This is the verification code entry page

```
class PhoneNumberVerification extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phonenumber;
  final FirebaseAuth auth;
  final String verificationId;
  const PhoneNumberVerification(
      {Key? key,
      required this.phonenumber,
      required this.auth,
      required this.verificationId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<PhoneNumberVerification> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String currentText = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void verifyOTP(
      FirebaseAuth auth, String verificationId, String smsCode) async {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0XFF0B1630),
                    Color(0XFF2C496A),
                  ]),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("asset/images/SpirationDark.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          child: Center(
            child: Align(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "We've sent you",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                          color: Colors.white,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "an OTP",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                          color: Colors.white,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(
                      "enter the 4-digit code we're sent on 9692499906",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SfProRounded',
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  PinCodeFields(text: currentText),
                  const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 2, 0, 0),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                            text: "didnt recieve code ?",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'SfProRounded',
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              letterSpacing: 0.5,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                            children: [])),
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                        width: width * 0.45,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // print(widget.verificationId);
                            verifyOTP(widget.auth, widget.verificationId,
                                currentText);
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const Home()));
                          },
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text("Verify"),
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: primarycolor,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, in the codeSent function can you print out verificationId? codeSent(String verificationId, int? resendToken) async { print(verificationId);}

And see what value is shown to the console